# $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ linearly dependent iff one of the $v_i$'s is a linear combination of the other $v_j$'s

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be any vector space.

Prove that the set $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ is linearly  <strike>independent</strike>  dependent if and only if one of the $v_i$'s is a linear combination of the other $v_j$'s where $v_k$ belongs to $V$, $1\leq k\leq n$.

Comment: You need to ask a question, show your thoughts, etc. "Solve this for me" isn't a question. Tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You must have meant linearly *dependent*. The original definition you must have been given is that some linear combination, with not all coefficients zero, gives the zero vector.

That is $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\cdots+a_nv_n = 0$. Assume $a_k\neq 0$. Then retain the term $a_kv_k$ and move all other terms to rhs. This gives
$$a_kv_k= - \big(\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}a_iv_i + \sum_{i=k+1}^n a_i v_i\big) $$

As $a_k\neq0$ we can divide all the scalars by this and get what you want:
$$v_k =  \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\frac{-a_i}{a_k}v_i + \sum_{i=k+1}^n\frac{-a_i}{a_k} v_i\bigg) $$